# Метод Рунге-Кутта 4 порядка на паскале

Tags: математика, pascal

Не могу сделать, чтобы задавать начальное условие y(x0)=1, если быть точнее, то не получается сделать ввод х0. Если кто может, исправьте, пожалуйста.

```
var
  k1,k2,k3,k4,x,y: array [0..100000] of real;
  h: real;
  i,n,n1: integer;

 
function f(x,y: real): real;
begin
  f:=x+y;
end;
 
begin
writeln('начало отрезка');
  read(n1);
  
  writeln('конец отрезка');
  read(n);

  writeln('шаг');
  readln(h);
  
  writeln('началное условие');
  readln(y[0]);
  
  for i:=n1 to n do
    x[i] :=i*h;
 
  for i:=n1 to n-1 do
  begin
    k1[i]:=f(x[i],y[i]);
    k2[i]:=f(x[i]+h/2,y[i]+h*k1[i]/2);
    k3[i]:=f(x[i]+h/2,y[i]+h*k2[i]/2);
    k4[i]:=f(x[i]+h,y[i]+h*k3[i]);
 
    y[i+1]:=y[i]+h/6*(k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i]);
  end;
 
  for i := n1 to n do
    writeln('x[',i:2,'] = ',x[i]:0:1,'   y[',i,'] = ',y[i]:0:4);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: @_Александр___, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @_Александр___, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У вас что-то не так с алгоритмом.

1. Если `n1` <> 0, то значение `y[0]` ни на что не влияет. Цикл, в котором вычисляются значения `y`, должен начинаться от нуля. Как-то так: `for i := 0 to (n - n1) div h do`.
2. Значения `x` в первом цикле тоже вычисляются неправильно. Если `n1` = 4, `n` = 11, а шаг 2, то значений `x` должно получиться 4 штуки (4, 6, 8, 10), а по вашему алгоритму их 7. Видимо, должно быть так:

   ```
   i := n1;
   j := 0; // integer
   while i <= n do
   begin
     x[j] := i;
     i := i + h;
     j := j + 1;
   end;
   ```
3. Не забудьте проверить полученные от пользователя числа на адекватность. h > 0, n > n1.
4. Последний цикл должен выглядеть, как второй: `for i := 0 to (n - n1) div h do`. И вообще, его можно и совместить со вторым.

P.S. Чтобы вам было понятнее, что вы делаете, называйте переменные со смыслом:

```
n1 = SegmentStart
n  = SegmentEnd
h  = Step
```